# Can JPA native query allow to use one Set Parameter for multiple condition

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

Below is my sample script.

```
getEntityManager()
.createNativeQuery("select * from TABLE1 T1, TABLE2 T2 where T1.DEPARTMENT_ID = :departmentId and T2.DEPARTMENT_ID = :departmentId") 
.setParameter("departmentId",departmentId) 
.getResultList();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you set a parameter called "parameterId" so you can then USE that parameter as many times as you want in the query. And the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's allowed but you can change your query to :

```
getEntityManager()
.createNativeQuery("select * from TABLE1 T1, TABLE2 T2 where T1.DEPARTMENT_ID = T2.DEPARTMENT_ID  and T2.DEPARTMENT_ID = :departmentId") 
.setParameter("departmentId",departmentId) 
.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible and in my case I have below query native working for me,

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("select i.customer_customerid, c.name 
from Invoice i inner join Customer c on c.customerid = i.customer_customerid 
where c.customerid=:id and i.invoicenumber=:id")
.setParameter("id",  1l)
.getResultList();
```